# Not able to get all document details from MongoDB whilst passing objectId through params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am only getting the object which is present in the Document...

this is the line of code of the route

```
router.get('/product-by-id/:ProductId', async (req,res) => {
    const {ProductId} = req.params; 
    const Id= await Prod.findById({_id:ProductId})
    return res.send(Id);
})
```

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose'); 
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:  'users'
    },
    title: {
        type:String,
        maxlength: 50 
    },
    description:{
        type: String
    }, 
    file: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String 
    }, 
    duration:{
        type:String
        
    }, 
    cat: {
        type:String,
        enum:["Shoes","Appliances","Apparel","Accessories","Electronics","Books","PC Parts"]
    },
    
    barter:{
        type: String
    }
}, {timestamp: true })

const Prod = mongoose.model('Prod', productSchema);

module.exports= Prod
```

I tested the route on Postman but only get the file object and not the others ...
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: try this `await Prod.findById(ProductId)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method looks good just a small fix is needed while using findbyId directly pass id. like this

```
let ProductId = req.params.ProductId
const Id= await Prod.findById(ProductId)
```